# Can Locks be garbage collected while locked?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, thread-safety

Can Locks (java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock) be garbage collected while locked?
Suppose a purely theoretical example:

```
WeakReference r;

public void foo(){
       Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
       r = new WeakReference(lock);   
       lock.lock();
}
```

Could `lock` be garbage collected after `foo()` gets executed? In other words, does `lock.lock()` create any strong references back to the lock?
How do you know?

Comment: As a relative Java newbie, I ask: Doesn't the mere virtue of instantiating a class implementing lock mean that you are working with something derived (even implicitly) from Object? Wouldn't this tell us that it is therefore strongly indicative since we don't see anything in the documentation about the classes that implement this interface that a lock's lifespan would be anything other than a normal object's? What makes you ask the question you did? Are you seeing strange behavior?

Comment: @San Jacinto: the question centers around the implementation details of the thread locking mechanism (lock.lock()). One can envision that threads could keep references to locks they own, or that there might be system monitors for active locks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A locked `Lock` can be garbage collected when it is no longer reachable.  (The definition of "reachable" in the JLS is: *"A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread."* - JLS 12.16.1)

However, a locked `Lock` that *some thread is waiting on* must be executing one of the Lock's lock / tryLock instance methods.  For this to happen, the thread *must* have a reference to the lock; i.e. one that the lock method is currently accessing.  Therefore, a locked Lock that some thread is trying to acquire is reachable, and cannot be garbage collected.

> In other words, does lock.lock() create any strong references back to the lock?

No.  In your example, the strong reference exists in the form of the `lock` variable.  But suppose that we tweaked your example to get rid of `lock`; e.g.

```
public void do_lock(WeakReference<ReentrantLock> r) 
   r.get().lock();
}
```

When you call `get()`, it will return a reference to the `ReentrantLock` object which will be held in a temporary variable or register, making it strongly reachable.  It will continue to be strongly reachable as long as the `lock()` call is running.  When the `lock()` call returns, the `ReentrantLock` object *may* become weakly reachable (again).

> How do you know?

How do I know?  A combination of:

- knowledge of the Java Language Specification's definition of reachability and other things,
- experience with implementing JVMs,
- good old-fashioned logic, and ...
- I confirmed it by reading the OpenJDK source code (though this doesn't *prove* anything about JVMs in general.)

There is not need to implement `Lock` using global queues, and hence no reason to have a hidden reference to the `Lock` object that would prevent it becoming unreachable.  Furthermore, a `Lock` that could not be garbage collected when it was locked would be a storage leak, and a major implementation flaw, and I cannot *imagine* Doug Lea et al making that mistake!

Comment: Stephen, you did not answer the "How do you know" part of the question. Also, from garbage collection standpoint, a lock "that some thread is waiting on" is no different than just a lock referenced by a strong reference. This question, of course, is about locks with no strong references.

Comment: @Oleg Ryaboy - the question is NOT "of course" about locks with no strong references!  You might have intended it to be, but nowhere in the question does it *say* that.

Comment: Thank you for checking the OpenJDK source code. Answer accepted!

Comment: Regarding a real use case for weak references to locks, I have a thread-safe weak-referenced memoizer used to manage a striped lock factory. This keeps the maximum number of locks down (for instance via some algorithm such as moduloing a numeric key) and has the benefit of recreating locks that are not used for a while, although this last property is most useful if the lock in question is a thin/fat lock implementation, but it does keep the resident memory consumption down.

Comment: @Jed Wesley-Smith - interesting.  Have you done any investigation to see how much performance increase / memory saving you get for this?

Comment: @Jed: That's exactly the reason I asked the question. The only difference is that I am using soft (not weak) references in my factory.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that while we often conceptually think that threads 'obtain' and 'own' locks, it's actually not the case from the implementation perspective. The locks keep references to owning and waiting threads, while the threads have no references to locks, and have no knowledge of the locks they 'own'.

The ReentrantLock implementation is also rather straightforward: there are no static collections of locks, and there are no background maintenance threads that keep track of locks.

Neither creating, nor locking a lock creates any 'hidden' new strong references anywhere, so, in the example above, the `lock` can be garbage collected once `foo()` is done.

One can verify this by perusing the source code:

http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock-source.html

http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer-source.html

http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractOwnableSynchronizer-source.html

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the only objects that cannot be garbage collected are the classes loaded by the bootstrap classloader (the rest are outgoing references to the former)

(java.util.concurrent.locks.)Lock(s) are absolutely normal objects, not different than java.util.ArrayList in terms of garbage collection. I have written locks w/ LIFO semantics (or specifically AbstractQueueSynchronized that is not FIFO), that's useful to minimized cache misses since the hottest threads get to work even more. Point is that is absolutely possible to write your own custom locking/sync/atomic code.

Comment: Please, if it possible, share your ideas or code how LIFO lock can be implemented, looking for such kind of component for efficient implementation of `FixedThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk, instead of adding to a queue, you use a stack and pop, hacking AbstractQueuedSynchronizer is not very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The Lock is not unlike any other object. It depends if some internal Java mechanism references the Lock. But I see no reason why Java should keep a reference to the Lock.

Answer (score 0):

It can be garbage collected while locked. No strong reference is created by taking the lock. As written, of course, you'd have to set lock to null and run the gc to see the reference go null.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean "after `foo()` gets executed", the answer is yes - that's really the point of WeakReferences.

You would know that because when you tried to convert the `WeakReference` `r` back into a regular (or strong) reference, you'd get `null` returned:

```
if (r.get() == null) {
    // the lock was garbage collected
}
```

Comment: Michael, the "how do you know" part of the question meant "how do you know that your answer is correct". I learned that, when it comes to garbage collecting, relying on opinion and intuition is not always the best idea.